# Доступ к файлам с расширением .css

Tags: php, css

Как средствами php запретить пользователю доступ к файлам с расширение .css?
Т.е. пользователь переходит на http://site.com/style.css, ему выдается ошибка 403

P.S. Знаю, что данная затея на 100% не защитит от кражи стилей, но всё же, хоть какой-то положительный эффект даёт.

Comment: Окей, и как пользователь тогда получит сами стили на странице?

Comment: @LiveStreet, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 2):

Абсолютно ненужная затея. Если стиль интересен, его скопируют в любом случае.

**Обновление**

Мое утверждение основано на том, что если сайт выложен в интернет, то его стиль доступен всем и не должен являться объектом трепета создателя. Если Вам необходимо защитить свои авторские права - обращайтесь в РАО до публикации сайта в общий доступ.

Comment: @densmith, Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Поясните, на чем основано ваше утверждение.

Comment: Обновил ответ.

Answer (score 1):

Его нельзя скрыть.

Answer (score 0):

Известный способ — проверять Referer.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://example.org [NC]
RewriteRule ^style.css$ - [F]
```

Правда, у меня файл css сохраняется в кэше, нужно нажать F5, чтобы появилась ошибка. Да и Developer Tools все равно файл покажет.